# about blocking a country by using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, blocking, apache2.4

I have tried many times, I feel desperate.
I have been able to do this successfully before on Apache 2.2.
Now my environment is Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server

I go to https://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx to generate code

1. select ipv4
2. select China
3. select "Apache 2.4 .htaccess deny"

Then add the code to the bottom of `.htaccess`.

However, the result is that I cannot access the website whether I use a VPN or not.

I am located in China．

Later, I tried to select another one country, such as Japan, to generate new blocking code.

However, the result was the same, after adding the code into `.htaccess`.
I also cannot access the website, even though the blocked country is Japan and I am in China.

I doubt the code, what should I do in order to get the right blocking a country code?

---

Some of the generated code:

```
<RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip 1.0.1.0/24
Require not ip 1.0.2.0/23
Require not ip 1.0.8.0/21
Require not ip 1.0.32.0/19
Require not ip 1.1.0.0/24
Require not ip 1.1.2.0/23
Require not ip 1.1.4.0/22
:
```

Comment: Sounds silly, but... does your IP address match any of the IP _(ranges)_ in the Apache directives?

Comment: thanks for reply,what you said help me to figure out the solution,the reason why I can not access even though using VPN maybe is that the VPN IP addresses are also blocked by it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now,I have solved the problem.

first of all,
the code generated from  https://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx is 100% correct!

the reason why I cannot access the website whether using VPN or not,is that I didnot add the following code to yourdomain.conf to make https(ssl) url also support rewrite.

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    .......

   <Directory "/var/www/html/yourdomainname/public_html">
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using GeoIP and .htaccess

I have **hostinger** server
To enable GeoIP, all you have to do is add the following line to your .htaccess file:

```
GeoIPEnable On
```

Once added, you can verify if it's working by creating a PHP Info file and checking the PHP Variables section:
[Image showing GeoIP is enabled in your server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wki6A.png)

**How to use it?**
To block access for perticular file in Britain, US and India:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^(GB|US|IN)$
RewriteRule (wp-login|xmlrpc).php$ - [F,L]
```

To allow access for whole website in Canada, UAE and India:

RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(CA|AE|IN)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L,QSA]